# Need of snmpd for sending traps

Tags: snmp

I am able to send traps out using command 'snmptrap' from my desktop(ubuntu)  without snmpDeamon running on it.
Why 'snmptrap' doesnot need 'snmpd'?

According to my knowledge 'snmpd' is SNMP agent, but how 'snmptrap' able to send traps without support of 'snmpd'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `snmptrap` is just a client which can send those SNMP traps to any other host running `snmpd` in your network. Your local `snmpd` has nothing to do with that unless it's the destination snmpd for your traps.

Here's an analogue: Your Firefox does not require Apache running at your laptop, you surf around the web just fine because your Firefox connects to remote web servers.

Comment: Do you mean , 'snmpd' should be running to receive traps?

Comment: I have stoped 'snmpd' but running 'snmptrapd' on ubuntu and able to receive traps

Comment: Uh, yeah, `snmptrapd` receives the traps. Anyway the `snmptrap` is just a client program.